# Freeze with fontspec's Renderer=OpenType + ItalicFont, biblatex, and polyglossia (Greek)

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, polyglossia, greek, luahbtex

(Continued in [LuaHBTeX Renderer=OpenType + BibLaTeX adventures part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541651))

It happens in a very specific situation,
these work fine in other combinations:

1. BibLaTeX
   (Greek works elsewhere)
2. Polyglossia: Greek
   (Russian works in BibLaTeX)
3. `Renderer=OpenType` with `luahbtex --fmt=lualatex`
   (`Renderer=Node` works)
4. Fontspec with this specific combo of `UprightFont` and `ItalicFont`
   (the most interesting one – swapping their values does not freeze but only shows italic!)

The fonts are version 2.104.
The log freezes too so I can't make any sense out of it.
How to even investigate what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ThisNameIsIrrelevant}[
    Extension=.otf,
    Renderer=OpenType,
    UprightFont=GaramondPremrPro,
    ItalicFont=GaramondPremrPro-It,
    %UprightFont=GaramondPremrPro-It,
    %ItalicFont=GaramondPremrPro,
]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=langname,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{test:greek,
    title = {Ξεσκεπάζω την ψυχοφθόρα σας βδελυγμία},
    author = {Κοραής, Αδαμάντιος},
    year = {1748},
    langid = {greek},
}
@book{test:russian,
    title = {Чушь гид вёз кэб цапф, юный жмот съел хрящ},
    author = {Достоевский, Фёдор Михайлович},
    year = {1821},
    langid = {russian},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

%\begin{greek}ήθος, \textit{πάθος}, \textsc{λόγος}\end{greek}
\nocite{test:greek}% the big freezer
%\nocite{test:russian}%
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image: desired PDF output]

Comment: I don't have GaramondPremrPro, so can't test.

Comment: I can confirm the problem.  Had to kill the process because my laptop was about to overheat.

Comment: @gnucchi Does it freeze if you specify no italic font at all?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger No, then it doesn't freeze. Setting `UprightFont` and `ItalicFont` to the same file (either both `GaramondPremrPro` or both `GaramondPremrPro-It`) also doesn't freeze.

Comment: Did the `luaotfload` update for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541651/35864 also resolve the issue here? Can you still reproduce the issue?

Comment: @moewe Yes, it's resolved. I cannot reproduce this issue with updated luaotfload.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was resolved by a `luaotfload` update.