# LuaHBTeX Renderer=OpenType + BibLaTeX adventures part 2

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, polyglossia, luaotfload, luahbtex

(Continued from [Freeze with fontspec's Renderer=OpenType + ItalicFont, biblatex, and polyglossia (Greek)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539325))

News:

- Author names and order matter (I wish I was joking: “Jane McGo” works but “Jane McGo***op***” crashes unless she comes first.)
- Not only Greek, also applicable without `autolang`. English breaks, Spanish works.
- Here the issue is not upright vs italic; here the issue is small caps applied to surnames.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}[
    Extension=.otf,
    Renderer=OpenType,
    %Renderer=Node,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{test:mcg,
    author = {Doe, John and McGoop, Jane},
    %author = {Doe, John and McGo, Jane},% McGoop → McGo
    %author = {McGoop, Jane and Doe, John},% switch order, same names
    title = {A Major Work of Art},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}% comment me
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{{\scshape #1}}% comment me

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}%
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: desired PDF output]

Comment: it seems to hang with the current version, but works with the development. But it is too late now to look more.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's the same underlying issue as in [luaotfload#141](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/141). We should probably release the current dev, the hyphen business can be dealt with in a separate release if necessary.

Comment: I can confirm applying [9e939b2](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/commit/9e939b2fc955be31c029e7ad057a607a41f82dfa) fixed both this problem and the previous question about Greek! I'm still curious though, how could simply changing the author result in a freeze like this?

Comment: @gnucchi The difference is that `McGoop` can get hyphenated into `My-Goop` while `McGo` and `Doe`  don't get hyphenated. That combined with the existance of kerning between all characters coming before the break triggered a bug in the handling of linebreaking handling of luaotfload.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Do you want to type up a short answer here so the question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of luaotfload had a problem with the HarfBuzz shaper when a hyphenation point occured involving on one of the first characters in a font.
This issue is resolved in current luaotfload versions, so you can fix your document by updating your version of luaotfload.

E.g. if you use TeXLive, run `tlmgr update --all` in your shell.

Comment: Thank you very much!